# Calling Web Service from AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying to call a Web Service method from AJAX call. Its working fine if I use 'localhost'. But, If I replace the 'localhost ' with specific IP address its giving me some script error.

**My code:**

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:1265/Service.svc/rh/VerifyConfirmationCode",
                type: "GET",
                datatype: "jsonp",
                data: { confirmationcode: 'MYCODE' },
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });

        function OnSuccess(data, status) {
            alert(data);

        }

        function OnError(request, status, error) {
            alert('error');
        }
```

Interface IService.cs :

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/VerifyConfirmationCode?confirmationcode={confirmationCode}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool VerifyConfirmationCode(string confirmationCode);
```

Class Service.cs

```
 public bool VerifyConfirmationCode(string confirmationCode)
    {
        return (confirmationCode.equals("MYCODE"));
    }
```

In the above code, If I change the URL to

```
url: "http://192.168.1.1:1265/Service.svc/rh/VerifyConfirmationCode"
```

I'm getting follwing errors,

> **'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied'** in the line 'w.open(m,e.url,e.async);' and 
>   **'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Could not complete the operation due to error c00c023e'** in the lines 'w.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",e.contentType);' and w.setRequestHeader("Accept",
>   e.dataType&&e.accepts[e.dataType]?e.accepts[e.dataType]+", */*":e.accepts._default)

of jquery-1.4.1.min.js file

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste exact exception?

Comment: Hi AshReva, Thanks for your resopnse. I've pasted the errors. Can you pls check?

Comment: are you able to execute that url from browser?

Comment: yeap, I am able to execute it. I checked with POSTER. Its giving me the correct response.

Comment: Please use Fiddler and compare RAW data which is send to service form your application and browser. If you want the service to work, both request should be similar.

Comment: didnt you used routing in your global.asax file?

Comment: is this 192.168.1.1:1265 your machine's IP address? It seems so because in localhost too i can see the same ip address. Why are you putting ip address?

Comment: I wanna access web service from another machine. The ajax call is working, if I deploy the web service in my machine and using the address as 'localhost' and its working neither for my IP address nor the another machine IP addess.

Comment: @janasoft can you try to remove port no from your url i.e remove :1265

Comment: I guess the issue with forming the URL. Getting the script error while forming the request with IP address.

Comment: Tried removing port number and got the same error. There are many services running on that machine. So port number is must.

Comment: @janasoft did you tried using routing in your global.asax. I use ajax call like this url: "../RestService/product/ProductLanguageList",